# How to open an app using ADB?

Tags: adb

I would like to modify an existing app from Google Play to not appear on the app drawer. So what I did is I decompiled the apk file and then removed the line: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">` from the manifest file and now the app does not appear in the app drawer.

Now, if I want to open the app (just like opening it if I press it from the app drawer), how can I do it using the ADB shell?

I read that we can use `adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name 1` to open an app but when I tried to use this it says `** No activities found to run, monkey aborted`.

Comment: Use `am start <packageName>/<activityClassName>` to start an app with the specified activity.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar which specific activity to start. I tried reading the manifest file and there are a lot of <activity> scopes, how can I know which activity to run that will open the whole GUI of app just like how it can be opened when pressed on the app drawer?

Comment: I would start with the activity you removed the `<category` line from as this is the activity used by the launcher.

Comment: *I would like to modify an existing app from Google Play to not appear on the app drawer* -- you might be trying too hard for this. There are some app launchers which can hide an app from app drawer (Nova Launcher 2 and Lawnchair2 do for sure). Very easy to do that. You can try them to see if that's all you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an app like [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher)
and if the app shows no activity to launch, that means in the process of decompiling you destroyed the app's ability to be launched.

And if you want to start the app from adb, you can take the activity name from Activity Launcher like this:

```
adb shell am start -n your.package.name/Activity Name from Activity Launcher
```